# Как вытащить последнюю запись из выборки таблицы?

Tags: mysql

Уникальный номер задачи

```
-----------------
| id | statusid |
-----------------
| 1 |     2     |
-----------------
| 2 |     1     |
-----------------
| 3 |     4     |
-----------------
```

История статусов задачи

```
-----------------
| ids | installed|
-----------------
| 1 |     1     |
-----------------
| 2 |     1     |
-----------------
| 3 |     3     |
-----------------
| 4 |     2     |
-----------------
| 5 |     1     |
-----------------
| 6 |     3     |
-----------------
| 7 |     4     |
-----------------
```

Выбрать последний установленный статус.

Результат

```
-----------------------------------
| id | statusid | installed | ids |
-----------------------------------
| 1 |     2     |    1      |  5  |
-----------------------------------
| 2 |     2     |    2      |  4  |
-----------------------------------
| 3 |     4     |    4      |  7  |
-----------------------------------
```

Я вытаскиваю двумя запросами, а как вытащить одним?

> UPD

***Сервер: Mysql 5.7***

Comment: А версию сервера указать - не?

Comment: @Akina подправил, хотя метка стоит.

Comment: Просто MySQL - это ниачём. В 8-й версии оптимальное решение будет совсем не таким, как в 5-й.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо да конструктивную критику. Как то не подумал про 8 версию)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рабочий вариант.

```
SELECT dpt.id AS bronId, dpt.project_id AS projectId, dpt.status_id AS statusId, dp.type, dsc2.comment_date AS commentDate, dsc.com_id
    FROM dealer_projects_tools AS dpt
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(dsc.id) AS com_id, dsc.tools_id
                 FROM dealer_status_comments dsc
                 GROUP BY dsc.tools_id )
               dsc ON ( dsc.tools_id = dpt.id )
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT dsc2.id, dsc2.tools_id, dsc2.comment_date
                 FROM dealer_status_comments dsc2)
               dsc2 ON ( dsc2.id =  dsc.com_id )
    INNER JOIN dealer_projects AS dp ON ( dp.id = dpt.project_id )
    WHERE dpt.status_id = 7
    ORDER BY dpt.id ASC LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Запрос не проверял:

```
SELECT st.id, st.statusid, tt.installed, tt.maxid
FROM status_table st
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(it.ids) AS maxid, installed
    FROM install_table it
    GROUP BY it.installed
) tt ON tt.installed = st.id
```

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста код: `JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(it.ids) AS maxid
    FROM install_table it
    WHERE st.statusid = it.ids
    GROUP BY it.installed
) tt ON tt.installed = st.id`

Comment: Если в таблице "История статусов задачи" записей по текущей задаче не найдется, то в результирующей таблице в поле `ids` будет `null`

Comment: Поправил немного ответ.

Comment: К каждой записи из первой таблицы джоним запись по условию `installed = id`, группируем по `installed` и выбираем строку с максимальным значением `ids`.

Comment: Не работает. Не видит `st.id`

Comment: Обновил ответ, проверил, запрос рабочий

Comment: @doox911 Сервер никогда не напишет "не вижу". Цитируйте сообщение сервера об ошибке... во избежание.

Comment: Решение не рабочее. `maxid` выводит корректно, `installed` - соответствует минимальному `id`

Comment: @doox911 Разве у Вас `id` задачи из первой таблицы не соответствует полю `installed` из второй таблицы?

Comment: Соответствует, но остальные поля то не подтягиваются. Наверно, мне стоило ещё пару столбцов указать.